# Automatically open Putty and SSH into server

Tags: windows-7, putty, automation

I am on Windows 7 and often need to open several PuTTY terminals to SSH onto a cluster machine at my workplace.

Is there a way to write a script that automatically opens two PuTTY sessions and logs me into them both? I have never automated much on Windows before... where would I start with something like this?

If possible, I would like one session to open with white text and a black background; the other with white text and black background.

Thanks

Comment: There's a PuTTY fork called Kitty which has some improvements in scriptability. It's still a drag. http://www.9bis.net/kitty/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to write a script that automatically opens two PuTTY sessions and logs me into them both?

Put something similar to the following into a plain text file (e.g. with Notepad):

```
start " " putty -ssh user@1.2.3.4 22 -pw Password1
start " " putty -ssh root@2.3.4.5 22 -pw Password2
```

Save this with a `.bat` (batch file) extension (ex. *opencluster.bat*). You can then double-click (or otherwise run) this file to open the listed sessions.

It's worth mentioning that if you don't have PuTTY registered in your Windows' `Path`, you should use `"C:\path\to\PUTTY.EXE"` in place of just `putty`.

**Saved Sessions**

If you have saved PuTTY sessions, you can omit the *host*, *port* and *connection type*. You can instead use `-load`, then give the session name in double-quotes. In this case, use `-l` (lower-case L) to specify the *user name* (`-pw` for the password remains unchanged):

```
start " " putty -load "SavedSession1" -l user -pw Password1
start " " putty -load "SavedSession2" -l root -pw Password2
```

**SSH Keys**

Note that you can use `-i` to specify a `.ppk` format private SSH key, if necessary. You can check out other command-line options [here](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline) (current for PuTTY 0.70).

> If possible, I would like one session to open with white text and a black background; the other with white text and black background.

To the best of my knowledge, this likely isn't possible. My understanding is that, unfortunately, PuTTY doesn't have any options to set colors when it starts.